# If an object is garbage collected in Flash, are the reference counters of objects it references decremented automatically?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, garbage-collection

I was thinking about Flash GC the other day and came up with a question about how reference counting would work in the following 4 class scenario (assume GuiMain is the movie's document class):

```
package com.gui {     
import flash.display.MovieClip;         
public class GuiMain extends MovieClip {         
 private var button1Handle:Button1;         
 public function GuiMain() {             
  // constructor code             
  button1Handle = new Button1();             
  addChild(button1Handle);            
  killButton1();         
 }                 
 public function killButton1(){             
  removeChild(button1Handle);             
  button1Handle = null;         
 }     
}     
}



package com.gui {     
import fl.controls.Button;    
import flash.display.*;         
public class Button1 extends Sprite {         
 private var button2Handle:Button2;         
 private var tester:Test;         
 public function Button1() {             
  // constructor code            
  button2Handle = new Button2();             
  tester = new Test();         
 }     
}     
}



package com.gui {         
public class Button2 {         
 public function Button2() {             
  // constructor code         
 }     
}     
}


package com.gui {     
import flash.display.MovieClip;     
import flash.events.Event;             
public class Test extends MovieClip{         
 public function Test() {             
  // constructor code            
  addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, yellLoudly);         
 }                 
 public function yellLoudly(e:Event){                         
  trace("AAAH!!!");         
 }     
}     
}
```

When the Button2 and Test instances are created in Button1, I would expect their reference counters to increment. The question is, do their reference counters decrement accordingly when the Button1 object that created them is removed from the display list and nulled out? I tested this code and the event listener in the Test class does seem to shut off, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it or the Button2 instance are eligible for GC. Even if they were, it might only be under Mark and Sweep, which is slower than reference count-based GC.

One obvious solution would be to have the Button1 class remove listeners from/null out references it makes when it is time for it to be removed like so:

```
package com.gui {     
import fl.controls.Button;     
import flash.display.*;         
public class Button1 extends Sprite {         
 private var button2Handle:Button2;         
 private var tester:Test;         
 public function Button1() {             
  // constructor code             
  button2Handle = new Button2();             
  tester = new Test();         
 }                 
 public function destroyRefs(){                   
  button2Handle = null;                   
  tester.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, tester.yellLoudly);                   
  tester = null;            
 }     
}     
}
```

but in a real program, where I may be working with multiple references to the same object from different classes (via passing in the original references in constructors) wouldn't setting the reference in one class to null cause the value of all other references to the same object to also become null? That would certainly be undesirable...

**The main question is as follows: when the only reference to Button1 is nulled out, do all the the objects it references have their reference counters decremented (either immediately or when the Button1 object is garbage collected)?**

Also, is there a way to view all instances of an object that exist in real time and/or their reference count values through the Flash debugger?  A detailed profiler like that would really help in figuring these questions out...

thanks,
CCJ

Comment: gah! you have to do something about that formatting!

Comment: Did I miss something, where are you adding tester to stage?

Comment: tester doesn't have to be added to the display list; its only purpose is to fill the debug console with unmistakable text.

Answer (score 3):

shameless self promotion, but this should help you: http://divillysausages.com/blog/tracking_memory_leaks_in_as3

Comment: If you want to link to your article, your answer ought to show how it's relevant to the question.

Comment: I think the link spells it out: tracking_memory_leaks_in_as3.
But, yeah, would be nice to give a little summary. (Makes a more effective self promotion too.)

Comment: good points :) it covers the basics of as3 garbage collection, both the reference counting method and the mark and sweep, as well as giving you a tool to help track memory leaks and easily see if objects are getting properly deleted, plus how to call the garbage collector in debug and release mode

Comment: also, @jeff, both flashdevelop and flash builder come with profilers that let you see how many objects were created and how many are still alive

Comment: thanks for the link; very informative!  Also, I found an open-source alternative to the Flash Builder profiler here: http://jpauclair.net/flashpreloadprofiler/  Haven't gotten to test it out yet, but its demos look great.

Comment: yep, his site is a goldmine of info :) Btw, flashdevelop is free and has the profiler built into ithttp://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page and there's also the general purpose deMonster debugger http://demonsterdebugger.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think of AS3 in terms of reference counting. If those objects created in Button1 are only accessible via Button1, then they're eligible for GC once you null out Button1. The exception is event listeners, you have to clean those up or those objects won't get cleared out. Flash doesn't take into account no objects are listening anymore.

Comment: yes, but what if the objects are accessible from outside of Button1?  The issue is I don't want to end up with ref counts for objects 'shared' between classes that can never reach 0 because another object that made reference to them no longer exists but failed to explicitly null out the references it made before it was GC'd.  If refs made by an object are automatically nulled out when it is GC'd, this is not an issue.  So that's the question really-- are references made an object nulled out when it is GC'd?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you don't need to worry about the reference count. If Object1 and Object2 both reference Object3, Object3 will be eligible for GC once both references are nulled out, timing of when those do that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This presentation http://onflex.org/ACDS/AS3TuningInsideAVM2JIT.pdf has a pretty good description of how garbage collection is implemented in AVM2 (the virtual machine that runs AS3).

Answer (score 0):

Ooo, a good question :)

As far as I know, Mark and Sweep is only used for reference counting event listeners since they're the only ones that can have 'weak listeners'.  Everything else is straight up memory reference counting.  Essentially, your biggest problem would be cleaning up event listeners, but if the event listeners are within your class (listening to itself, or it's children or even outside events) they should be GC'ed properly if the object is dereferenced throughout your app (don't store it somewhere else).

If you let object or properties be publically visible, it is possible for other classes to references them and it could prevent GC of your class (it really depends how it's referenced and all).  The only to combat that is to try to encapsulate as much as possible (one class handles it's own dereferencing; look into IDisposable) so that others can't reference and try to adhere to good coding practices (preventing spaghetti code).